# Finding the prime numbers used in RSA

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I got this question in a local hacking event, but I couldn't solve it.

Problem Statement ----

Continuing their snooping habit, NSA kept bugging Alice's communication. Resorting to the age old RSA encryption, Alice used 128-bit RSA encryption to exchange messages. Alice shares her public key as

> $0xffffffa95256a837568a41c265f4fe27110814aae19f144762d5cc0bcb931807$

and her public key exponent `$\phi(n)$` as `$0x11$` with Warden.

However, NSA, with its enormous resource, cracked this 128 bit encryption super easily. Seeing your work on the previous ciphers, NSA decided to offer you a job in their Cryptography group. As a final test, NSA shared this public key which they intercepted from Alice and Warden's conversation. They also gave away the private key that they computed from their message exchange.

> $Public$ $Key -
>   (0xffffffa95256a837568a41c265f4fe27110814aae19f144762d5cc0bcb931807,
>   0x11)$
>
> $Private$ $Key -
>   (0xffffffa95256a837568a41c265f4fe27110814aae19f144762d5cc0bcb931807,$ 
>                         $0xc3c3c3817b3335577e69b9d0e48e2bc1fdf71f1f4f73a38a7d628d39739bbaf1)$

What are the values of `$p$` and `$q$`? (the prime numbers used in key generation)

Comment: Consider asking the question on [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/). I am sure guys there are better prepared for the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about crypto, not programming.

Comment: [cross posted on crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13113/how-can-i-find-the-prime-numbers-used-in-rsa)